# C#: Alignment of text into a DataGrid for data loaded from a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment

The scenario is to change the alignment of the text of a cell based on its contents. But the data is in a DataGrid which gets its values from a DataTable. How can i change the alignment when its loaded into the DataGrid. Thanks!

[My Grid should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk7AA.png)

Comment: Straight from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `DataGrid` or `DataGridView`?

Comment: Yes DataGrid. The data from the DataTable is then loaded onto a DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Alignment` of `Style` in the `DataGridViewCell`:

```
cell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
cell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

And as you know, the `cell` variable can be initialized like:

```
DataGridViewCellcell = dataGridView1[1,2];
```

Comment: But i wanted to access it from a DataGrid. After some searches i found that i wont be able to access a cell in a DataTable. But how do i access a row?